# Seg fault when reading a line into dynamically allocated char pointer array

Tags: c, posix

In C, I am trying to implement a function that uses `getline()` to read all the lines from a file. It is implemented similarly to `getline()`, specifically the fact that it is using `realloc()` to resize a `char**` if there is not enough memory allocated to store the next pointer to a line. Unfortunately I am getting seg faults during the string dupilcation process.

After a little poking around, I discovered that the segfault happens during the second iteration while attempting to store the second line in the char pointer array.

```
ssize_t fgetlines(char*** linesptr, size_t* n, FILE* fp)
{
    char* line = NULL;
    size_t sz_line = 0;
    size_t cur_len = 0;
    size_t needed;

    if (linesptr == NULL || n == NULL) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    if (*linesptr == NULL) {
        if (*n == 0)
            *n = sizeof(**linesptr) * 30; /* assume 30 lines */
        *linesptr = malloc(*n);
        if (*linesptr == NULL) {
            *n = 0;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    while (getline(&line, &sz_line, fp) > 0) {
        needed = (cur_len + 1) * sizeof(**linesptr);
        while (needed > *n) {
            char** new_linesptr;
            *n *= 2;
            new_linesptr = realloc(*linesptr, *n);
            if (new_linesptr == NULL) {
                *n /= 2;
                free(line);
                return -1;
            }
            *linesptr = new_linesptr;
        }
        *linesptr[cur_len] = strdup(line);
        printf("%s", *linesptr[cur_len]);
        if (*linesptr[cur_len] == NULL) {
            free(line);
            free(*linesptr);
            return -1;
        }
        ++cur_len;
    }

    free(line);
    return cur_len;
}
```

And I call the function like so:

```
    char **settings = NULL;
    size_t sz_settings = sizeof(*settings) * 6;
    int count = fgetlines(&settings, &sz_settings, f_cfg);
```

Due to the function not being able to successfully complete I do not get any output. But after printing back the string after `strdup()` I managed to get one line of `f_cfg`, `"Hello World"` before a seg fault.

Comment: @ three-strar-progammer: split it into separate functions, and you will see the light

Comment: dylif,  Is `*linesptr[cur_len]` the same as `*(linesptr[cur_len])` or `(*linesptr)[cur_len]`?  [ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: `new_linesptr = realloc(*linesptr, *n);` -> `new_linesptr = realloc(*linesptr, *n * sizeof **linesptr);` (you are reallocating *pointers*) And `while (needed > *n)` can simply be `if  (needed > *n)`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin OP have a code hole here too - what if `*linesptr != NULL, *n == 0`?  `*n *= 2;` does not help much.

Comment: chux, thanks for pointing this out but after changing `*linesptr[cur_len]` to `*(linesptr[cur_len])`, I am still getting the segfault.

Comment: I'd expect you want `(*linesptr)[cur_len]`.  `*linesptr[cur_len]` is the same as `*(linesptr[cur_len])`.

Comment: @chux, I will fix that right away. Thanks for showing me that.

Comment: @David C. Rankin, n is already bound to `sizeof **linesptr` earlier. Nonetheless, I did try both your and chux's ideas, however I am still getting a segfault.

Comment: Nevermind, made a stupid mistake and forgot to change all references to `*linesptr[cur_len]` to `(*linesptr[cur_len])`, thank you both for pointing out these flaws!

Comment: Happens... Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should change

```
*linesptr[cur_len]　 =>  (*linesptr)[cur_len]
```

The modified function is as follows:

```
ssize_t fgetlines(char *** linesptr, size_t *n, FILE *fp)
{
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t sz_line = 0;
    size_t cur_len = 0;
    size_t needed;

    if (linesptr == NULL || n == NULL) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    if (*linesptr == NULL) {
        if (*n == 0)
            *n = sizeof(**linesptr) * 30; /* assume 30 lines */
        *linesptr = malloc(*n);
        if (*linesptr == NULL) {
            *n = 0;
            return -1;
        }
    }

    while (getline(&line, &sz_line, fp) > 0) {
        needed = (cur_len + 1) * sizeof(**linesptr);
        while (needed > *n) {
            char **new_linesptr;
            *n *= 2;
            new_linesptr = realloc(*linesptr, *n);
            if (new_linesptr == NULL) {
                *n /= 2;
                free(line);
                return -1;　// Possible memory leak
            }
            *linesptr = new_linesptr;
        }
        (*linesptr)[cur_len] = strdup(line);
        printf("%s", (*linesptr)[cur_len]);
        if ((*linesptr)[cur_len] == NULL) {
            free(line);
            free(*linesptr);
            return -1;  // Possible memory leak
        }
        ++cur_len;
    }

    free(line);
    return cur_len;
}
```

In addition, when your memory allocation fails, the memory of "strdup" is not free, which will lead to memory leak.